# Help to find a factorization of a matrix into a product and sum of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, factoring

if  $\hspace{0.2cm}$$Z\in$ **R**$^{n\times n} $ $\hspace{0.2cm}$is the down-shift matrix with ones on the first subdiagonal and zeros elsewhere,  and  $L\in$ **R**$^{n\times n} $ $\hspace{0.2cm}$ is the lower triangular matrix with $1s$ at the non-zero entries, then the matrix
$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
w_1 & w_1  &\cdots & w_1 \\
w_1 & w_2 & \cdots& w_2  \\
\vdots & \vdots  & \ddots& \vdots  \\
w_1 & w_2 & \cdots & w_n\\
\end{array}
\right)$$
can be written as $\hspace{0.2cm}$ $A=L(D_w-ZD_wZ^T)L^T$$\hspace{0.2cm}$ where $\hspace{0.2cm}$$D_w=Diag[w_1,\cdots,w_n]$

If I have the matrix
$$B=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
w_1 & w_2  &\cdots & w_n \\
w_2 & w_2 & \cdots& w_n  \\
\vdots & \vdots  & \ddots& \vdots  \\
w_n & w_n & \cdots & w_n\\
\end{array}
\right)$$
How can I to factorize it in a similar way to the previous matrix in terms of $Z$ and $L$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $K$ denote the matrix with $1$s on the "antidiagonal", i.e.
$$
K = \pmatrix{&&1\\&\cdots\\1}
$$
We note that "flipping" the matrix $B$ gives us
$$
KBK = \pmatrix{
w_n&w_n&\cdots&w_n\\
w_n&w_{n-1}&\cdots&w_{n-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
w_n & w_{n-1} & \cdots & w_1}
$$
Let $D_\hat w$ denote the matrix $\operatorname{Diag}[w_n,w_{n-1},\dots,w_1]$ (if you prefer, you could write $D_{\hat w} = KD_wK$). Using your decomposition, we have
$$
KBK = L(D_{\hat w}-ZD_{\hat w}Z^T)L^T \implies\\
B = KL(D_{\hat w}-ZD_{\hat w}Z^T)L^TK
$$
Or if you prefer,
$$
B = (KL)(D_{\hat w}-ZD_{\hat w}Z^T)(KL)^T
$$